# How should I prove the required independence given the tedious distribution expression of $Y_i$?

Tags: probability-distributions, permutations, independence

**Problem.** Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be a ranking of the yearly rainfalls in a city over the next $n$ years. Assume that $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ is a random permutation of $1,2,...,n$. Say that $k$ is a record year if $a_k \lt a_i$, for all $i \lt k$. Thus the first year is always a record year. Let $Y_i=1$ if $i$ is a record year, and $0$ otherwise. Find the distribution of $Y_i$ and show that $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ are independent.

---

**My Attempt.** I could handle the distribution part. To find $\mathbb P(Y_i=1)$, I divided the number of permutations for $Y_i=1$ by the total number of permutations (i.e. $n!$), where the former number was found by considering cases when $a_i=1,2,...,n-i+1$. What I got was a bit tedious:
$$\mathbb P(Y_i=1)=\frac{(n-i)!}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\frac{(n-1-j)!}{(n-i-j)!}$$
I did sanity checks for $i=1$ and $i=2$, and they turned out to be correct. Hence, I think this intimidating expression is probably right. But then I have had no idea how to proceed to prove the required independence, because the calculations would be evidently crazy.

---

**Comments.** I am not asking for a complete answer to the problem; just some helpful hint is enough, for which I will give my green tick if my question is not closed. Please leave me some space for independent thinking. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233446/independence-of-records-of-permutation

Answer (score 1):

**Hints if you don't want to see the full answer yet**:

(I didn't invent these, I looked it up on other posts on Stackexchange)

$\\$

If you have $n$ tickets numbered $1$ to $n$ in a hat and randomly pulled out $k$ of them, one at a time, what is the probability that the last one you pulled out has the biggest number out of the $k$ tickets?

$\\$

Let $1\leq c_1<c_2<\ldots <c_{j+1} <n$. You take out $c_{j+1}$ of your $n$ tickets, one by one, and see whether the last one was the biggest yet. If it is, you re-assemble the first $c_j$ cards you took out, put these in a separate hat, took these out randomly one by one again, and examine the new pattern you get.

What's the difference between doing that and just taking $c_j$ cards instead of $c_{j+1}$ cards in the first instance?